# Description for String[] entries

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, list

so i'm working on a project and i need the following to work:

Let's say I have a String[] contatining out of f.e 3 values "0D", "0A", "01A0"
Now in the background I got like a defined description for each of these values and I want to show them in another string.
So in the end i want to call a method with String"0D" and the method returns me the description, in this example "speed"
same for the others, if i call the method with "0A" it returns String "Fuel Pressure"

Is there an efficient way for achieving this? Cause i've got a pretty long list and don't want to manually input all the descriptions to the commands..

Comment: Looks like a `Map<String, String>` to me.

Comment: If you're using some kind of device interface, you might find it more useful to have `Map<Short, String>` or something. Depends on the real datatype of that hex data you have

Answer (score 1):

Yeah a HashMap would work.
You could try this:

```
HashMap<String, String> valueDescription = new HashMap<>();
valueDescription.put("0D", "speed");
valueDescription.put("0A", "Fuel Pressure");
valueDescription.put("01A0", "Temperature");

public String getDescription(String value) {
    if (valueDescription.containsKey(value)) {
        return valueDescription.get(value);
    } else {
        return "Description not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and can i add a third value, like a boolean? So the 1. is command, 2. is description and 3. is value 0/1 or false/true?

Comment: Yeah you can store a Boolean but you can't do that directly in the hashmap. You would need to create a class containing the info (Description and your Boolean) with getter. Then in the HashMap you would do this:
 `HashMap<String, ValueDescription> valueDescription = new HashMap<>();`
You also need to adjust your `getDescription()` method and some sort of `getBoolean()` method to return the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a [hashmap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) of `<String, String>`. The key would be the command, and the value is the description.